# How to query for Integer in Array saved with type converter in Room Database?

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

I am saving a List in my Room database using a typeconverter. Now i would like to query the db and retrieve object where the List contains a specific integer. 
For example:
Object1 List contais the integer 1, 2, 3 and when i query just for integer 1 it retrievs Object 1.

Here is what i am trying:
My Entiy:

```js
@Entity(tableName = "exercises")
public class Exercise {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "api_id")
    private int apiId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "exercise_name")
    private String exerciseName;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_path")
    private String imagePath;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "youtube_key")
    private String youtubeKey;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "exercise_type")
    private int exerciseType;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "muscle_group")
    private List<Integer> muscleGroup;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "secondary_muscles")
    private List<Integer> secondaryMuscles;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "notes")
    private String notes;
```

My type converter:

```js
@TypeConverter
    public static String fromList(List<Integer> list){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        return json;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<Integer> fromString(String string){
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(string, listType);
    }
```

My Dao:

```js
@Query("SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE muscle_group LIKE :muscle")
    LiveData<List<Exercise>> getByMuscle(List<Integer> muscle);
```

And my ViewModel:

```js
private LiveData<List<Exercise>> exercises;

    public LiveData<List<Exercise>> getExercises(Context context, int muscleGroup){
        if(exercises == null){
            loadData(context, muscleGroup);
        }
        return exercises;
    }

    private void loadData(Context context, int muscleGroup){
        List<Integer> muscle = Arrays.asList(muscleGroup);
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getInstance(context);
        Log.d(TAG, "Load data from database");
        exercises = db.exerciseDao().getByMuscle(muscle);
    }
```

Someone has an idea if this what i want is possible? or will i need to do a workarround like retrieving all and than select in a for loop? Thanks for your inputs.